# Need to check disk space on /dev/disk2

Tags: macos, terminal

So, I have a raspberry pie 3 B. I wanted to know how much space is used so I plugged the micro sd card in my mac and opened the terminal.
When I ran the command:

```
    df -h /dev/disk2
```

I got:

```
    df: /dev/disk2: Raw devices not supported
```

What should I do now?

PS: I don't want to plug the RPI in.

Comment: You need to mount the file system, mounting is the process of telling a driver to translate the raw bytes of the disk to structure that can contains files and folder (and has a size)

Comment: Questions about general computing hardware and software are off-topic for Stack Overflow unless they directly involve tools used primarily for programming. You may be able to get help on Super User.

Answer (score 0):

You'd indeed need to mount the disk first, like Ferrybig said.

*Note*: It could be, since it's for the RPI, that you SD card is formatted with one of the EXT file system variants. To access those under MacOS, you'll need something like [FUSE](https://osxfuse.github.io/) (free, but I have never used) or [Paragon's ExtFS](https://www.paragon-software.com/home/extfs-mac/) (commercial, I've used it quite often). Some SD cards for the RPI are FAT32 formatted - those should work just fine under MacOS.

Easiest way to mount a volume, if you don't want to mess too much with the commandline parameters, is by opening Disk Utlity. Find the disk/partition you'd like to mount, right click it and select "Mount". This works for "known" file system types.

Now after the disk has been mounted, type "mount" in terminal to see where it's mounted. It will show several lines, one of them could be (as an example):

```
/dev/disk2s1 on /Volumes/Untitled (ntfs, local, nodev, nosuid, read-only, noowners)
```

(there may be more that start with "/dev/disk2sX")

`df- h /Volumes/Untitled` will now show the disk space info, for example:

```
Filesystem     Size   Used  Avail Capacity iused    ifree %iused  Mounted on
/dev/disk2s1   15Gi   57Mi   15Gi     1%      19 15239289    0%   /Volumes/Untitled
```

If your disk2 has multiple partitions, then you'd need to repeat the steps for all disks that start with "/dev/disk2sX" (where X is a number).